# « 石の上にも三年 » littéralement : « en restant assis sur un rocher trois ans »

Tags: expressions, japonais

Je cherche une expression française équivalente à la maxime japonaise « 石の上にも三年 », ou ce qui s'en rapproche le plus.
L'adage veut qu’il ne faut pas se laisser abattre facilement face à la première difficulté rencontrée mais y consacrer des efforts soutenus pour toucher au but.

Aussi froid au toucher que puisse être un rocher, c’est avec patience qu’on arrive à le rendre suffisamment chaud. À force de rester assis au même endroit assez longtemps (pendant trois ans d'affilée !), on en viendra à se sentir réchauffé, même sur un rocher froid.

Answer (score 6):

A page xiii (16 sur 300) dans la Résume de  sa thèse intitulée :
 [*Changement identitaire et revendications régionalistes au Kansaï, Japon*](https://papyrus.bib.umontreal.ca/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1866/10357/Kanzaki_Sachiyo_2013_these.pdf),
Sachiyo Kanzaki  traduit  *石の上にも三年* littéralement comme

« Même trois ans sur un rocher »

et donne

> *Tout vient à point à qui sait attendre*

comme son équivalent français en remerciant une certaine Karine Picard pour sa patience tranquille. (via *papyrus.bib.umontreal.ca*)

> [**Tout vient à point à qui sait
>   attendre**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tout_vient_%C3%A0_point_%C3%A0_qui_sait_attendre#Locution-phrase)
>   (via *fr.wiktionary.org*)
>
> On arrive à tout avec de la patience.
>   Comme quoi, « tout vient à
>   point à qui sait attendre », et tout finit par se savoir. —
>   (Jean-Michel CARTIER, Louis PORCHER, Apprendre et enseigner d’hier à
>   aujourd’hui, 2010)

---

To the extent that Professor Kanzaki’s being slightly off with her literal translation of the original expression in question (see OP’s comment below) might tempt one to question her choice for its French equivalent (and with it my reliance on that choice in this answer), I will suggest a second possibility (albeit old, if not archaic) for consideration.  One that acknowledges the importance of something in addition to mere waiting and patience, as follows:

> [**AVEC LE TEMPS ET LA PAILLE, LES NÈFLES MÛRISSENT**](HTTPS://CITATIONS.OUEST-FRANCE.FR/CITATION-PROVERBE-FRANCAIS/TEMPS-PAILLE-NEFLES-MURISSENT-72407.HTML)
>   (from *citations.ouest-france.fr*)

Attesting perhaps much more to its age than to its relevancy to your question, the entry for [“nèfle”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/n%C3%A8fle) in *Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française, édition 1762* (via *CNRTL*) mentions the proverb as meaning that:

> On vient à bout de bien des choses avec du soin & de la patience.

Although “les soins” required in *石の上にも三年* might seem more like a **lack** of “soins,”or at least a lack of action, sitting on a rock for three years straight with the goal of warming it is a feat that, in my opinion, would exhibit a level of [tender, loving] care at least equal to that of a hen covering her eggs!

Comment: Oh, just in case this affects an answer, I need to point out that a literal translation suggested by this person is actually slightly off: « **Même** trois ans sur un rocher » should be changed into « Trois ans **même** sur un rocher ». The intensifying particle "にも/même" qualifies the part "sur un rocher", not "trois ans".

Answer (score 4):

> ***Patience et longueur de temps***
>
> *Font plus que force ni que rage.*

[Quand bien même](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/quand-bien-meme/) dans la fable *[« Le Lion et le Rat »](http://www.lafontaine.net/lesFables/afficheFable.php?id=34)*
Jean de La Fontaine attribue cette maxime
à une autre situation, c’est le mot *[patience](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/569/patience-et-longueur-de-temps-font-)* qui l’emporte ici.